# How to sort the contents of a text file

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort the content of a text file. Currently, I'm sorting it using excel. I wanted to use python script to automatically sort the contents.

The code below does not produce the needed output. Any idea will be very much appreciated.

```
  def sorting(filename):
    infile = open(filename)
    words = []
    for line in infile:
      temp = line.split()
      for i in temp:
        words.append(i)
    infile.close()
    words.sort()
    outfile = open("result.txt", "w")
    for i in words:
      outfile.writelines(i)
      outfile.writelines(" ")
    outfile.close()

  sorting("myfile.txt")
```

Current code output:

```
 -0.162 -0.638 -2.248 -2.348 -3.427 -4.622 0.00 0.162 0.176 -> more data...
```

myfile.txt # file needed to be sorted

```
  ABC1234     -2.385      05:58
  1234DCE     -3.430      05:58
  98ACD12     12.574      05:58
  18DDD12    11.564   05:58
  453FGH2A    0.351   05:58
  A2DA21     0.00     05:58
  8FF3EFA    -0.720   05:58
  ABC1234     -2.348      06:11
  1234DCE     -3.427      06:11
  98ACD12     11.883      06:11
  18DDD12     10.883      06:11
  453FGH2A    0.176   06:11
  A2DA21      0.162   06:11
  8FF3EFA     0.888   06:11
  ABC1234     -2.248      06:18
  1234DCE     -4.622      06:18
  98ACD12     13.356      06:18
  18DDD12    10.915   06:18
  453FGH2A    0.00    06:18
  A2DA21     -0.162   06:18
  8FF3EFA    -0.638   06:18
```

Intended Output: # to be sorted based on the latest time.

```
  Name       06:18      06:11    05:58      
  ABC1234    -2.248    -2.348    -2.385     
  1234DCE    -4.622    -3.427    -3.430      
  98ACD12    13.356    11.883    12.574     
  18DDD12    10.915    10.883    11.564     
  453FGH2A    0.00      0.176     0.351       
  A2DA21     -0.162     0.162     0.00       
  8FF3EFA    -0.638     0.888    -0.720
```

Comment: What is your sort criteria? One of the columns? Is this file in a known format such as Tab Separated Values (TSV)?

Comment: It seems like you want to aggregate data based on name in the first column and time from the last column each becoming its own column header.

Comment: I wanted to sort based on the time column. The file contains 3 columns and separated by spaces.

Comment: No, you don't.  That's not what your sample output is at all.  Your sample output has the rows aggregated, so that all rows with ABC1234 are collected into one row.  That is NOT sorting.  That is aggregation.  In your sample output, NONE of the columns is sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't usually argue for pandas as the first solution, but in this case I think it is the right answer:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {}
for row in open('x.csv'):
    cols = row.rstrip().split()
    if cols[2] not in data:
        data[cols[2]] = {}
    data[cols[2]][cols[0]] = cols[1]

print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
{'05:58': {'ABC1234': '-2.385', '1234DCE': '-3.430', '98ACD12': '12.574', '18DDD12': '11.564', '453FGH2A': '0.351', 'A2DA21': '0.00', '8FF3EFA': '-0.720'}, '06:11': {'ABC1234': '-2.348', '1234DCE': '-3.427', '98ACD12': '11.883', '18DDD12': '10.883', '453FGH2A': '0.176', 'A2DA21': '0.162', '8FF3EFA': '0.888'}, '06:18': {'ABC1234': '-2.248', '1234DCE': '-4.622', '98ACD12': '13.356', '18DDD12': '10.915', '453FGH2A': '0.00', 'A2DA21': '-0.162', '8FF3EFA': '-0.638'}}
           05:58   06:11   06:18
ABC1234   -2.385  -2.348  -2.248
1234DCE   -3.430  -3.427  -4.622
98ACD12   12.574  11.883  13.356
18DDD12   11.564  10.883  10.915
453FGH2A   0.351   0.176    0.00
A2DA21      0.00   0.162  -0.162
8FF3EFA   -0.720   0.888  -0.638
```

(Side note -- you could eliminate two lines of code by using `defaultdict` for `data`.  In this case, I don't think it's worth the trouble.)

Comment: `pandas` has a thousand different options for display output, but you might even want to write this to an Excel file (`to_excel`) so you can format it as you need.

Comment: Is it possible to sort this output based on the latest column `06:18`?

Comment: You need to read about pandas.  It is a hugely capable package.  Look for `sort_values`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tim Roberts nailed it. The two things I'll add are here:

df = df.sort_values(by=[df.columns[-1]]) #sorts by the last column
df.to_csv("csv.csv") #writes to a csv

So in all:

```
import pandas as pd

def sorting(filename):
    data = {}
    for row in open(filename):
        cols = row.rstrip().split()
        if cols[2] not in data:
            data[cols[2]] = {}
        data[cols[2]][cols[0]] = cols[1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df = df.sort_values(by=[df.columns[-1]]) 
    df.to_csv("csv.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be, reading the txt file as Pandas DataFrame and pivot table afterward.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf("file.txt", header=None)
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=[0], columns=2, values =1, aggfunc='first').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename(columns={0:'Name'})
df.to_csv("output.txt", sep='\t', index=False)
```

Comment: This solution if based on txt file.